# Fire event on textbox lose focus

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events, textbox

I'm trying to call a method as soon as a TextBox on my screen gets 'un-focused' if that makes any sense? The user types in a username and as soon as that textbox loses focus I want to fire an event that checks if that username is indeed available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `Control.Leave` in C#, which I think is perfect for your purpose.

you can go to events of the textbox in visual studio, and find the `Leave` event.

The code generated will be like :

```
private void txtbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //Check for available operation Code
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you very much, in Windows Phone it's called TextBox_LostFocus. But all the same. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

Please explore the `LostFocus` event in a `textbox`. Hope it helps

Comment: I can't see the **LostFocus** event into the list of events of the Properties panel in MS C# Express 2008. I can only see **Leave** event.

Answer (score 0):

select your object and to choose the panel of the properties and click on event.To unroll until LEAVE and double-click above.that will give you:

```
private void  object_Leave( object  sender,  EventArgs  e)
{
  ////put your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF Try this:
**TextBox.LostFocus**

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Go to the "properties" of your textbox. You will see a yellow lightning bolt in the first line tab. There you will find all possible events that can be triggered. Search for "Leave" entry, double-click it. There you can put whatever you want.